# Unable to load JasperReports classes in PHP script using JavaBridge and Docker

Tags: java, php, jasper-reports, php-java-bridge

I’m using Docker to run a PHP script that uses JavaBridge to connect to a Java server. I have installed JavaBridge, Tomcat, and JasperReports. When I run my PHP script, standard Java classes such as **java.util.ArrayList** work fine, but I’m unable to load JasperReports classes such as **net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager**.

I’ve tried setting the **CLASSPATH** environment variable in various ways, including in my **docker-compose** configuration **(CLASSPATH=/opt/bitnami/jasperreports/WEB-INF/lib/*)**, through the terminal, and in an environment file. I’ve also tried adding different folders containing JAR files to the **CLASSPATH**. However, the JasperReports classes still cannot be found.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated!